# add path or draw path between to points googlemaps

Tags: android

Want to ""add path or draw path ""between two points (two overlay items ) to  appear in Google maps using Android ! how to do this ? ( drawing path between two points )

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display a path (following a road/rail) then you need to use the google maps api (either using a json object parsing or xml parsing) to get the path between 2 points, 
if you just want to draw a line between two points (euclidean distance) then you can simply draw it using the canvas and the paint functions. Google either of these queries and you should hit tutorials.The person above has provided tutorials for the first option.
goodluck.

Comment: what if i want to do the second choose can u give me a link !!